# Select with two counts same column different where

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions

I have  a table with

```
Logdate,Status

    20190101 ok
    20190101 notok
    20190101 ok
    20190102 ok
    20190102 notok
```

I would like to get a query result like these:

```
date     ok  notok
20190101 2   1
20190102 1   1
```

I don't know hot make a query of same column agreggate with 2 different where's
Please any help?
Thanks!

edit--- mi querys

```
SELECT LOGDATE AS EXECUTION_DATE, COUNT(1) AS TOTAL_OK FROM CMR_IOALOG WHERE UPPER(STATUS) LIKE upper('% OK %') group by logdate ORDER BY LOGDATE DESC;
SELECT LOGDATE AS EXECUTION_DATE COUNT(1) AS TOTAL_NOTOK FROM CMR_IOALOG WHERE UPPER(STATUS) LIKE upper('%NOTOK%') group by logdate ORDER BY LOGDATE DESC;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation, via a case expression inside the `count()` call:

```
select logdate,
  count(case when status = 'ok' then status end) as ok,
  count(case when status = 'notok' then status end) as notok
from your_table
group by logdate;
```

The `count()` function ignores nulls, so the case expression gives a not-null value for the status you want to count, and defaults to null for anything else.

Demo with your sample data as a CTE:

```
-- CTE for sample data
with your_table (logdate, status) as (
            select 20190101, 'ok' from dual
  union all select 20190101, 'notok' from dual
  union all select 20190101, 'ok' from dual
  union all select 20190102, 'ok' from dual
  union all select 20190102, 'notok' from dual
)
-- actual query
select logdate,
  count(case when status = 'ok' then status end) as ok,
  count(case when status = 'notok' then status end) as notok
from your_table
group by logdate;

   LOGDATE         OK      NOTOK
---------- ---------- ----------
  20190102          1          1
  20190101          2          1
```

Hopefully your `logdate` is actually a date rather than a number; I've just used a number to match the value you showed. If it is a date and has non-midnight times then you can `trunc(logdate)` to count values across the whole day:

```
with your_table (logdate, status) as (
            select to_date('20190101 00:01', 'YYYYMMDD HH24:MI'), 'ok' from dual
  union all select to_date('20190101 00:02', 'YYYYMMDD HH24:MI'), 'notok' from dual
  union all select to_date('20190101 00:03', 'YYYYMMDD HH24:MI'), 'ok' from dual
  union all select to_date('20190102 00:01', 'YYYYMMDD HH24:MI'), 'ok' from dual
  union all select to_date('20190102 00:02', 'YYYYMMDD HH24:MI'), 'notok' from dual
)
select trunc(logdate) as logdate,
  count(case when status = 'ok' then status end) as ok,
  count(case when status = 'notok' then status end) as notok
from your_table
group by trunc(logdate);

LOGDATE            OK      NOTOK
---------- ---------- ----------
2019-01-02          1          1
2019-01-01          2          1
```

---

You could use `sum()` instead, and make the case expression evaluate to either zero or one, but the effect is the same - and I prefer to use `count()` when the overall aim is to count things.

You could also use an explicit `pivot`, but it does the same thing under the hood, and is probably overkill for this simple scenario.

Answer (score 1):

```
-- Oracle 11+
with s (Logdate,Status) as (
select 20190101, 'ok'    from dual union all
select 20190101, 'notok' from dual union all
select 20190101, 'ok'    from dual union all
select 20190102, 'ok'    from dual union all
select 20190102, 'notok' from dual)
select *
from s
pivot (count(*) for status in ('ok' as ok, 'notok' as notok))
order by Logdate;

   LOGDATE         OK      NOTOK
---------- ---------- ----------
  20190101          2          1
  20190102          1          1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select logdate, ok, notok from your_table 
    pivot (count(status) for status in ('ok' as ok, 'notok' as notok));
```

Comment: Sorry I forget is postgree. I edit main post and I put the querys that works but give me in two querys instead one

Comment: Pavel, you are using group by step twice. Look at the query plan.